# Does CasperJS provide references to the underlying PhantomJS objects?

Tags: javascript, automation, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm migrating a script from [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org) to [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org), and am wondering if Casper provides any references to the Phantom objects that it is using behind the scenes.

Phantom provides some functionality that Casper doesn't (injectJs, for example).

For completeness' sake, here are all of [Phantom's objects](http://phantomjs.org/api/):

- [webpage](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/)
- [system](http://phantomjs.org/api/system/)
- [fs](http://phantomjs.org/api/fs/)
- [webserver](http://phantomjs.org/api/webserver/)
- [child_process](http://phantomjs.org/api/child_process/)

By looking at the `casper` object's properties, I did find a reference to the `webpage` object (`casper.page`), so my particular use case is handled.  I figured I would post this question anyway in case other people need access to system, fs, webserver, or child_process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know that with the `system` and `fs` modules, you are able to use the same APIs as you would with CasperJS as you would with PhantomJS. This is most likely true for `webserver` and `child_process` as well. What I mean by this, is that you can continue to require these modules as you would with PhantomJS, ex:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var sys = require('system');
```

As for `webpage`, you can take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16629231/395353) as to how to access the `page` object that CasperJS uses to run on top of PhantomJS.

Comment: Good stuff, hope this helps someone!

Comment: "This is most likely true for `webserver` and `child_process`" - This is true for `child_process` since implementation of [issue#515 "add support for phantomjs child_process"](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/issues/515)

Answer (score 1):

Here an example about how you can use the webserver module in CasperJS

[CasperJS passing data back to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852987/casperjs-passing-data-back-to-php/16489950#16489950)