# Use onAuthPrompt() with CasperJS and SlimerJS

Tags: casperjs, http-authentication, slimerjs

SlimerJS added a `onAuthPrompt` callback. Is it possible to get it to work with CasperJS?

I found mention that the phantomjs or slimerjs object is available as `casper.page`, and then the following answer said that `casper.page` is only available after calling `casper.start()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16629231/841830

So I tried this code. The `onAuthPrompt` code is taken from the documentation; I just added a log line to make sure it works.

```
casper.test.begin("first",function suite(test){
  casper.start();

  casper.page.onAuthPrompt = function (type, url, realm, credentials) {
    console.log("onAuthPrompt: type="+type+",url="+url+",realm="+realm+",credentials="+credentials);    //TEMP
    credentials.username = "laurent";
    credentials.password = "1234";
    return true;
    };

  casper.thenOpen(url,function(){
    console.log('Loaded:'+url);
    test.assertSelectorHasText('#msg','');
    this.capture('1.png');
    });

  casper.run(function(){test.done();});
});
```

It loads `url` (which does not require auth), then an `XMLHttpRequest` or `EventSource` connection is made, which is what requires authentication. I see the password prompt pop-up but my `onAuthPrompt()` function is not getting called.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this not what onAuthPrompt is for, or could it be a bug that I could report (but in that case, do you think the problem is in CasperJS or in SlimerJS?).

Comment: What version of SlimerJS are you using? It looks like this feature was only added in version `0.9.0`.

Comment: @hexid Thanks, I'm using 0.8.3, which is the latest release at slimerjs.org (Sep 17th 2013). I've not managed to track down which commit onAuthPrompt was in, but it doesn't seem to have been since then.

Comment: I will try a pure slimerJS test using that functionality, and see if and when it gets called...

Comment: According to the documentation, it was added with 0.9.0. http://docs.slimerjs.org/nightly/release-notes.html#new-api

Comment: @hexid Aha! Thanks. So, it is vapourware currently, and they are documenting before releasing (which is a nice approach). I think if you post that as an answer I can give you the tick. ...But hang on, the code for it was committed 3 months ago: https://github.com/laurentj/slimerjs/commit/0304aaf3ab2dcd125a8f5892ebb4b03da83d4366  I wonder why it wasn't in the 0.8.3 release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the [`onAuthPrompt`](http://docs.slimerjs.org/nightly/manual/http-authentication.html#by-a-callback) callback was added in version 0.9.0, which has yet to be released.

You can check the documentation from the master branch of the Git repo [here](http://docs.slimerjs.org/nightly/release-notes.html).

There is also the latest released documentation (v0.8.3) [here](http://docs.slimerjs.org/0.8/index.html)